# How to verify if command in the thread is successfully started in Java and another thread can be started?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have several threads and one of them is running HTPP service using ProcessBuilder.

```
HttpThread class

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process pb.start();
process.waitFor();
int exitValue = process.exitValue();
```

I would like to have another thread wait when the service is started. What is the best way to do it?

Sleep doesn't seem to me good solution. Perhaps would be possible to use some method HttpThread.isReady(boolean b)  but I couldn't setup this flag since after starting the command the service stays up and running and the thread is waiting when service will be finished.

Another way can be create one more thread and do socket connection but also not sure if it's good solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an instance of the [Producer/Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem.  Why don't you just use the `wait/notify` mechanism?

Here's an academic [example](http://puma.wellesley.edu/~ecom/lecture/ConsumerProducerRight.html).

Comment: Amir, where do you put in example class above the code for notify?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking where the notify call is located in the example I posted?  Or are you asking where the notify call would go in the example you posted?

Comment: I apologize if it's not clear. Your example already contains all class and my questions related to the example I posted. The reason I'm asking is that I don't see it's the same issue. Please clarify or give example.

Comment: The idea is that one thread will wait on a condition variable to proceed.  The other thread, when finishing it's work, will Notify any thread whose waiting on the same condition variable.

Comment: This is what I want, but in this case it doesn't work as given in example since HttpThread works as Http service and it means it stays up and running if command is correct and I need I need to know if it's started. Take a look on another answer. I think I will implement one of the proposed options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are rather limited, since the HTTP service exists outside the JVM.

1. You could poll the other process using inter-process communication, such as a socket.
2. You could block until the process writes a ready message to [`Process.getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29).